# Create SVG / XML document without ns0 namespace using Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, svg

I'm building an SVG document with ElementTree in Python 2.7. Here is the code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

root = etree.XML('<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>')
root.append(etree.Element("path"))
root[0].set("d", "M1 1 L2 2 Z")
print etree.tostring(root, encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

This generates the output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%"><path d="M1 1 L2 2 Z" /></ns0:svg>
```

This does not parse as valid SVG.
How can I remove the ns0 namespace?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I just figured it out and I can't delete the question so here it is:

```
etree.register_namespace("","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
```

I think this only works as of Python 2.7 though.

Comment: Answering your own question is much better than deleting it. If someone later has this question, it will already be answered and indexed!

Comment: If you need compatibility with older Pythons (or even if you don't), you might be better off using [`lxml.etree`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html): this is more or less a superset of what's provided by `xml.etree`.  Has some external dependencies, though.

Comment: lxml is notorious for not working on OS X out of the box. They don't provide a precompiled egg for Intel macs and trying to compile it from scratch is extremely hard. The only way to get it working quickly is if you're using macports, which I don't feel is an acceptable dependency.

Comment: As someone who googled `python xml ns0` and got your answer, I'm pretty grateful this wasn't deleted ;)

Comment: Some extra info: if you are using a different namespace in your xml, you obviously need to change the url in the register_namespace call to match your namespace.

Comment: @jfenwick, where in your code (after which line) do you put the `register-namespace` method?

Comment: @sbru, sorry for being 9 years later, but `import xml.etree.ElementTree as et;
et.register_namespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")` is what I did to make it work in python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it with lxml.

```
from lxml import etree
svg_tree = etree.fromstring(svg_str, parser=etree.XMLParser())
etree.tostring(svg_tree)
```

Used sample code from here:
[lxml-removing-xml-tags-when-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232252/lxml-removing-xml-tags-when-parsing)